# How to Add an image in the bottomAppBar

Tags: windows-8

I want to add an ImageBrush in the ApplicationBar.
The image comes from a Web Server.
How to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple

```
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<AppBar ><AppBar.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="./Assets/bg.png"></ImageBrush>
            </AppBar.Background></AppBar>
    </Grid>
```

As for loading the image from the web, do that in code and then bind the imagesource property to the appropriate property in your viewmodel

Comment: How do you mean not relevant, this is how I do it.